# How to use POST method in asp.net web api method in objective c?

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, xcode7.3, ios9.3.2

ASP.NET  Web API application defines post method to shortlist userDetails which uses complex-view model data.

.h

```
#define URL "http://101.127.236.85:6067/tmsservice/MobileService.svc/AddTimeSheet"
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

{

 [super viewDidLoad];

    [self sendRequestWithPostType];
}


- (void) sendRequestWithPostType
{
    NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@URL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];


    [request addValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request addValue:@"iOS" forHTTPHeaderField:@"DeviceType"];

    [request addValue:@"123456" forHTTPHeaderField:@"DeviceID"];

    [request addValue:@"05e2954e-9ba6-4ab3-84af-5793b55bc69f" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



    [request addValue:@"0"forHTTPHeaderField:@"TimeSheetID"];

    [request addValue:@"16/9/2016" forHTTPHeaderField:@"EntryDateString"];// Selected Entry Date

    [request addValue:@"4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"EmployeeID"];

    [request addValue:@"Ram Kadam" forHTTPHeaderField:@"EmployeeName"];

    [request addValue:@"70"forHTTPHeaderField:@"ProjectID"];

    [request addValue:@"Azure Discovery" forHTTPHeaderField:@"ProjectCode"];

    [request addValue:@"Azure Discovery" forHTTPHeaderField:@"ProjectName"];

    [request addValue:@"3"forHTTPHeaderField:@"ActivityID"];

    [request addValue:@"Prototype" forHTTPHeaderField:@"ActivityName"];

    [request addValue:@"8.5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Hours"];

    [request addValue:@"Under UAT Testing" forHTTPHeaderField:@"WorkDone"];

    [request addValue:@"2"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Status"];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"conn:= %@",conn);

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{

    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error

{

  NSLog(@"Did Fail");

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data


{

    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

  NSLog(@"Did Finish");

    jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
                JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                error:nil];

    NSLog(@"jsonObject is %@",jsonObject);

}
```

Response:-

URL: http://101.127.236.85:6067/tmsservice/MobileService.svc/AddTimeSheet

Did Finish

jsonObject is (null)

Please tell me where I am wrong in this code.

Comment: Please reformat your question

Comment: @Shriram Kadam don't use nsurl connection, it is depreciated, use Nsurlsession

Comment: Hello Imran, How can I use Nsurlsession? Can you please tell me or reenter with in my code?

Comment: any buddy help me? how to use POST Method with JSON parameter with Using Nsurlsession?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURLSession to POST, here is a example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://101.127.236.85:6067/tmsservice/MobileService.svc/AddTimeSheet"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
// your header key-values
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"key1": @"value1"};
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// your body key-values
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key1": @"value1"};
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                               options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (!error) {
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                               fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
                                                                   // Handle response here
                                                               }];
    [uploadTask resume];
}
```